# Фоновая картинка поверх градиента

Tags: html5, css3

Стоит задача сделать полупрозрачную фоновую картинку поверх градиентного фона в хедере. Градиент всегда остается, а картинку можно заменить на любую другую, чтобы она оставалась нужной прозрачности.
В коде ниже отображается только картинка, без прозрачности.

```
.header
    width: 100%
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #fce38a, #f38181)
    position: relative
    overflow: hidden
    height: auto
    &::before
        background: url('/img/bg-top.jpg') no-repeat center
        opacity: 50%
        position: absolute
        content: ''
        display: block
        height: 100%
        width: 100%
        left: 0
        right: 0
        z-index: 100
```

Comment: положить ещё один DIV под низ и градиент перенести в него

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grimg {
width:100px;
height:50px;
border-radius:5px;
box-shadow:0 5px 0 0 #AD871D;
background: #f2ff63;

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2ff63 1%,#ffe92b 100%);
position:relative;
}
.grimg:before {
content: '';
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
top:0;
background: url(http://www.softfully.com/pics/debian.png);
background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grimg"></div>
```